# Función MAX en MySQL con varios registros con ese valor máximo

Tags: sql

No consigo encontrar la sentencia que me devuelva cuáles son los equipos que han obtenido el máximo número de victorias en una tabla básica con equipos y número de victorias.

Por ejemplo:

```
equipo victorias
a       2
b       1
c       2
```

En este caso yo quiero que me devuelva:

```
a, 2
b, 2
```

Y eso es lo que no sé como hacerlo porque al poner

```
SELECT MAX(VICTORIAS), nombre_equipo FROM EQUIPOS
```

No me devuelve lo que quiero.

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad.

Comment: De dónde saldría ese `b, 2` en el resultado esperado??

Comment: Si me equivoco, perdón. Gracias a los tres por las respuestas. Para otra vez me leeré el tutorial de cómo preguntar para hacerlo mejor. A los otros dos compañeros, ya me han resuelto la duda, pero muchas gracias igualmente por el interés y las respuestas. 

Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Para este caso puedes usar Subselect dado que necesitas específicamente los que tengan un valor máximo, también esta la opción de usar GROUP BY ,pero eso te traerá todos los registros.

```
SELECT * FROM EQUIPOS WHERE VICTORIAS = (SELECT MAX(VICTORIAS) FROM EQUIPOS);
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, esto era justo lo que buscaba! 

Un saludo!!